# Buried PVC lline for irrigation not under pressure

Tags: exterior

This line has been in the ground for 4 years and is not under much pressure.  This morning I saw a spray of water coming out of the ground. Upon digging I found 5 or six pin holes in the line.  They are close to a join.

What could cause this?

Water is drained in the winter.

Comment: the pink liquid use to roughen PVC for glue to stick, might have been used excessively

Comment: what grade pvc?  class 160, 200, or schedule 40? I think I read it here that a home owner installed a long water line using 200 and over used the primer and glue on the joints.  EVERY SINGLE JOINT FAILED. had to dig up and replace the entire run.   Also, I'm puzzled that "pin holes" could cause a spray coming out of the ground.  Much more likely it's a failed connection.

Comment: Ground movement. Critters chewing on the pipes. All sorts of reasons for in-ground plumbing to fail. Maybe [edit] a picture in showing the damage - someone may see something you're not seeing. Also, it's likely to be under the exact same pressure as the rest of the plumbing in your house, so unless your inside water pressure is low, your outside pressure probably won't be low either.